# compare integer text field value with mysql data in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to check whether the newly entered data is already in the table

**code:**

```
txtNo   = new JTextField();
{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String srcurl1      = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_name"; 
        Connection con      = DriverManager.getConnection(srcurl1,"root","paswrd");
        Statement stmt1     = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1       = stmt1.executeQuery("select No from bank where No='"+txtNo.getText()+"' ");

        int ch =rs1.getInt("No");
        int ch4= Integer.parseInt(txtNo.getText());

        if(ch==ch4)    // input 58 == 58
         System.out.println("already exits");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
    }
}
```

**Error :**
`Exception:java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.`

Comment: What is the sql type for the column *No* in your database? Is it declared as an integer or a varchar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the result set has elements or not:

```
while(rs1.next())
{
    int ch = rs1.getInt("No");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: while(rs1.next()){
int ch =rs1.getInt("No");
 int ch4= Integer.parseInt(txtNo.getText());
if(ch==ch4) {
....
}}
still getting exception where i going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `ResultSet` first to check to see that it contains rows:

```
if (rs1.next()) {
   int ch =rs1.getInt("No");
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this exception when the select statement returns an empty set. Add a try/catch block which acts upon the knowledge that the data is not already in the table in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check whether a particular record exists in the database might be just as follows:

```
Select 1 from bank where No = [your_supplied_value]
```

This query would return 1 if it finds a row in your database with the supplied data or return an empty resultset. So, all you need to check is whether ANY value is returned in the resultset or whether it is emtpy.

Here's a sample code to get you started:

```
txtNo   = new JTextField();
{
    try {
        String compareText = txtNo.getText().trim();

        if(compareText.length() > 0){
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String srcurl1      = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_name"; 
            Connection con      = DriverManager.getConnection(srcurl1,"root","paswrd");
            Statement stmt1     = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs1       = stmt1.executeQuery("select 1 from bank where No='"+txtNo.getText()+"' ");

            boolean isPresent = rs1.next();

            if(isPresent){
                System.out.println("Already exists!!");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
    }
}
```

I hope this is not your final code, because there're several problems with it:

- You're not managing your resources properly. Once you're done querying your database, you should consider closing your resultset, statement and connection objects.
- Note that I checked whether the text in the JTextField is empty or not. This is a good way of preventing a call to the database when you know that the text field had no value in it.
- I would suggest using a PreparedStatement rather than a Statement for querying to your database.

Answer (score 0):

A `ResultSet` is initially positioned **before** the first row. So you need to call `next()` to move it to the next row (and check that it returns `true`) before you call one of the `getXXX()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
JTextField input = new JTextField();
ArrayList < Integer > list = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
int integerv = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_name", "root", "yourpassword");
    Statement stm = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select column_name from table_name");

    while (rs.next()) {
        list.add(rs.getInt(1));
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < list.Size(); a++) {
        if (a.get(a) == integerv) {

            System.out.println("Match found");

            break;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Match not found");
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error :" + e.getMessage());
}
```